# Printer Features Do not appear in Printer Properties in Advanced tab in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printing, printer, pcl

I am using windows 7 with PCL5 driver for printer. My printer model is HP LaserJet 4100. I  am using PCL 5 driver and i have a problem my printing preferences do not appear Printer Features and other options in different tab. I have uninstall and re-install printer and it's driver BUT problem remain the same.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zI0eN.png)

Comment: You're probably using a generic driver. Try a driver from https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-laserjet-4100-printer-series/83436

Comment: @hdhondt sir i do not use generic driver i install driver manually from add a printer -->Add a Local printer ---> Install the printer driver and where i select the Manufacturer and Specific Printer. Thanks for your reply but the problem still exist.

Comment: Try downloading the driver I gave and run it to decompress the files. Then install as a local printer. When asked for the printer model, click on "Have disk" and browse to the location of the downloaded files.

Comment: @hdhondt Sir it install a HP Universal printing PCL6 Not a specific printer PCL5.